# Incorrect dimensions for raising a matrix to a power

Tags: matlab

Here is my code:

```
x = 60: 95;
r11 = 0.93;
E1=13.5;
F1=0.00529;
G1=0;
H1=1;
k11=60;
k12=0;
uid = 10^-7*1.31275 * exp(0.145961 * x );
P = exp(-F1 * ((x-k11)^2) - G1*(x-k12));
fi= E1 * P + H1;
y1 = r1 * fi * uid;
plot(x,y1);
```

My error is:

> Error using  `^`  (line 51)
>   Incorrect dimensions for raising a matrix to a power. Check that the matrix is square and the power is a scalar. To perform elementwise matrix powers, use '`.^`'.
>
> Error in `ui12` (line 16)
>   `P = exp(-F1 * ((x-k11)^2) - G1*(x-k12));`

Comment: Please do a basic search before you post a question. Copy-pasting your question title into Google yielded the linked Q&A as first answer. I’m even sure you were presented the link when typing your question.

Answer (score 2):

The error refers to the snippet `(x-k11)^2`, where you subtract a scalar (`k11`) from an array (`x`, 1x36) and try to square the result. The problem is that the function `^` is the shortcut for the function `mpower()`, which is the *matrix-power* function and consequently expects a scalar or a matrix calculation as it essentially is

```
x^2 == x*x
x^3 == x*x*x
```

However, it does not know what to do with an array as `x*x` does not work (try do run `rand(1,36)*rand(1,36)`, which will essentially raise the same error).
It also suggests a solution: `.^`, which is the element-wise power function (in fact, the `.` in an arithmetic operation usually indicates that the following operation is conducted *element-wise*). This `.^` is the shortcut for the "normal" `power` function as you would have expected in the first place. It performs the `^2` to every element of the array `x`.

```
x.^2 == power(x,2)
```

**extended side note**:
To mimic the behavior of the *element-wise* operator `.`, you may want to have a look at the `arrayfun` function, which applies a certain function to every element of a matrix or array/vector. If you are a new with matlab (as I assume from your question), this hint may just confuse you.

```
x.^2 == arrayfun(@(a)mpower(a,2),x)
```